# Is there an app/service that allows you to create a remote database for AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This service is to help with setting up a front-end web app for which the back-end isn't ready or available -- the service gives you temporary endpoints to send AJAX requests to, and returns the data you specify.

I know I've seen something like this before, but I can't think of the name. And no amount of Googling is helping. Do you know the app/service I'm referring to? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not set up a local server?

Comment: Firebase, Parse or something like BigQuery?

Comment: You can keep it all local with something `jQuery.ajax.fake` (https://github.com/anasnakawa/jquery.ajax.fake).  We use the _request_ object in `amplify.js` which allows the same type of approach for this purpose.  You can see more about that here: (http://www.elijahmanor.com/mocking-jquery-ajax-with-amplifyjs-request/)

Comment: You're probably thinking of the ["noBackend" stuff](http://nobackend.org/solutions.html), specifically http://remotestorage.io/

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @PHPglue No, not using JQuery.

Comment: All -- @meager's link to "noBackend" was what I needed. Deployd was the one I'd come across before. Even so, the info about JQuery was helpful, and much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a database at all. If you just want to test your AJAX to see if it can be sent to a Server page, then see if it gets returned to your JavaScript upon success, I would write a tiny bit of PHP, like:

`test_ajax.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
else{
  // $_POST super global is not set
}
?>
```

The only problem is that this code does not test for anything specific. It just spits out the data that you are sending through AJAX, via JavaScript, which you can see when your `requestInstance.readyState === 4 && requestInstance.status === 200`. Change `$_POST` to `$_GET`, if using the `get` method.

Assuming you are using jQuery's `.post()` method:

```
$.post('test_ajax.php', {property:'value', check_this:'stuff out'}, function(r){
  // use firebug's console or output to html instead
  console.log(r);
  // should return the object {"property":"value", "check_this":"stuff out"}
}, 'json');
```

Same as:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'test_ajax.php',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{property:'value', check_this:'stuff out'},
  success:function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
  }
});
```